# How can I use journalctl to time-filter and view non-journal files?

Tags: logs, syslog, journalctl

I'm trying to search through dozens of logfiles that were not sent to systemd-journald, and would like to filter the results by time, the way journalctl's `-S` (since) and `-U` (until) do.

- Option 1: write a program that reads lines, parses timestamps, prints filtered output
- Option 2: use /usr/bin/dateutils.dgrep from the Ubuntu dateutils package
- Option 3: convert the logfiles into journal format and use `journalctl --root $dir -S xxx -U yyy`

I started on #1, realized I was reinventing the wheel, tried #2, found that it was incredibly slow, and then looked at #3, mainly because it's fast, polished, and has had many "eyeballs" (especially "paid eyeballs") looking at it.

So, is there a tool that will convert syslog-style logfiles into journal files such that the entries can be filtered by time?  `Systemd-cat` won't work, because it's not allowed to forge timestamps: the resulting journal file will say everything happened at roughly the same time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Edit:

The log files are > 100MB, there are close to a hundred of them, the timestamps are plain syslog-style "MMM DD HH:MM:SS", and I just want to say "show me the log entries between these two times".

Option #1 was "write a program to do it", but I'm certain this wheel has been reinvented many times already; I'd feel foolish adding one more (mediocre) wheel to the pile.

Option #2 hadn't finished even one file before I gave up after half an hour. Essentially, I want a fast general solution that can be reused, and `journalctl` looked like a good part of the answer.

I reckon that `journalctl` takes advantage of the monotonically increasing timestamps of log files and uses binary search to find records in a given time range. The `dateutils.dgrep` (`dategrep`) program isn't allowed to make that assumption, which makes it slower than molasses in January.

Edit2:

It looks like writing a short script to parse the input logs, emit the records in journal-export format, and use systemd-journal-remote to generate a journal file would work:

```
journalctl -n 10 -o export > journal.txt
/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote -o test.journal journal.txt
journalctl --file=test.journal -S "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" -U "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
   (log entries for time range shown)
journalctl --verify --file=test.journal

PASS: test.journal
```

Initially I thought that the `__CURSOR` lines might contain sealing checksums, but deleting them had no obvious effect.  It appears that Forward Secure Sealing is not enabled by default on Ubuntu 20.04, but journalctl does detect if log entries are not monotonically increasing:

```
rm -f test.journal
/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote -o test.journal journal.txt
/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote -o test.journal journal.txt
journalctl --verify --file=test.journal

3947a0: Entry timestamp out of synchronization                                                                                           
File corruption detected at test.journal:3947a0 (of 8388608 bytes, 44%).                                                                 
FAIL: test.journal (Bad message)
```

It seems it will be fairly easy to import any arbitrary logfile into journal format and access it with journalctl.

Comment: You didn't say:  How big are the log files; how bad are the timestamps; what do you want to do with the timestamps? You can use `date --date=STRING "+%s"` (see `man date`) to parse the dates for `-U`, `-S` and the timestamps on each line to convert timestamps to "the number of seconds since the Beginning of Time" to integer values that can easily be compared. After that, it's a simple matter of scripting

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 - filter log files by time (skip journal conversion)

> *I'm trying to search through dozens of logfiles that were not sent to systemd-journald, and would like to filter the results by time, the way journalctl's -S (since) and -U (until) do.*

If you only want to view the syslog-style log files in a particular datetime range, then try [`super-speedy-syslog-searcher`](https://crates.io/crates/super-speedy-syslog-searcher). This uses features of `super-speedy-syslog-searcher` and skips the use of the systemd journal log service.

Assuming you have [rust installed](https://rustup.rs/), run

```
$ cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

Then run `s4` on the directory containing the log files

```
$ s4 /logs
```

To confine to particular datetime range, pass `-a` and `-b` options to filter by datetime. An example processing of log files using datetime filtering

```
$ cat /tmp/logs/kernel.log
<6>Jan  1 13:58:25 HOST kernel: [44033.150723] eth0: link up (100Mbps/Full duplex)
<6>Jan  2 12:01:00 HOST kernel: [194033.150723] loop7: detected capacity change from 0 to 113888

$ cat /tmp/logs/syslog.1
<29>Jan  1 13:58:25 HOST netifd: Network device 'eth0' link is up
<86>Jan  3 15:00:36 HOST dropbear[23732]: Exit (root): Disconnect received

$ s4 -a "2023-01-02T00:00:00Z" -b "2023-01-03T00:00:00Z" /tmp/logs/
<6>Jan  2 12:01:00 HOST kernel: [194033.150723] loop7: detected capacity change from 0 to 113888
```

---

### Option 2 - convert log files into journal files

> *is there a tool that will convert syslog-style logfiles into journal files such that the entries can be filtered by time?*

#### Overview

A sequence of operations to convert the syslogs would be:

1. use [`super-speedy-syslog-searcher`](https://crates.io/crates/super-speedy-syslog-searcher) to reprint logs with specially formatted datetime.
2. use [`journalctl`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/journalctl.1.html) to convert each syslog message to a basic logger message in line-oriented [*journal export format*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html)
3. use [`systemd-journal-remote`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-journal-remote.socket.8.html) to import the messages

#### 1. use `super-speedy-syslog-searcher` to reprint a log file

Given a log file `/tmp/logs/syslog.1` with syslog-style messages

```
<29>Jan  1 13:58:25 HOST netifd: Network device 'eth0' link is up
<86>Jan  3 15:00:36 HOST dropbear[23732]: Exit (root): Disconnect received
```

Using `super-speedy-syslog-searcher` (`s4`), reprint lines with file name (`-n`) and leading datetime as a Unix Epoch in microseconds (`-d '%s000000'`) in UTC timezone (`-u`).

```
$ s4 -n -u -d '%s000000' /tmp/logs/syslog.1
syslog.1:1672610305000000:<29>Jan  1 13:58:25 HOST netifd: Network device 'eth0' link is up
syslog.1:1672786836000000:<86>Jan  3 15:00:36 HOST dropbear[23732]: Exit (root): Disconnect received
```

#### 2. use `journalctl` to convert a syslog message to a journal format message

Here is an example of creating a minimal contrived journal format log message using `logger`:

```
$ echo "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=logger
MESSAGE=one journal logger message
MESSAGE_ID=$(uuidgen)" | logger --journald -s

$ journalctl -n1 -t logger
Feb 03 00:48:01 HOST logger[445736]: one journal logger message
```

Here is that message exported to *journal export format*

```
$ journalctl -n1 --identifier=logger --output=export
__CURSOR=s=4a35367b4dd3403b948f1a5ff2fb3515;i=474833;b=5285cccfe2f9481ca12589f5511b8c57;m=dd9ee>
__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1675414081923660
__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP=951851827460
_BOOT_ID=5286cccfe2f9481ca1ea8cf5221b8c5e
_UID=0
_GID=0
_MACHINE_ID=333fa82c526bba518cdc8c2262e6d480
_HOSTNAME=HOST
_TRANSPORT=journal
SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=logger
MESSAGE=one journal logger message
MESSAGE_ID=4ebd2168-30bf-4258-bf0f-54b5811674e1
_PID=445736
_COMM=logger
_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1675414081923606
```

#### 3. use `systemd-journal-remote` to import a journal log message

To import a contrived message, resend similar data to the journal service using `systemd-journal-remote`.

For the log messages, each new journal entry only needs parameters `MESSAGE_ID`, `MESSAGE`, `_TRANSPORT`, `__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP`, `_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP`.
Set `_TRANSPORT` to `syslog`. Override values `__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP` and `_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP` with the datetime stamp as microseconds since Unix Epoch. For *Jan 1 15:00:36 2023 PST*, the value is *1672614036000000*.

```
$ echo "\
__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1672614036000000
_TRANSPORT=syslog
MESSAGE_ID=4ebd2168-30bf-4258-bf0f-54b5811674e1
MESSAGE=one journal logger message
SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=logger
_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1672614036000000
" | /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote --output=/tmp/tmp.journal -

$ journalctl --output=short-full --file=/tmp/tmp.journal
Sun 2023-01-01 15:00:36 PST logger: one journal logger message
```

#### putting 1., 2., and 3. together

Put all this together into a short shell script that will process a directory of log files `/tmp/logs` into journal files at `/tmp/logsj`.

Given syslog-style log files:

```
$ cat /tmp/logs/kernel.log
<6>Jan  1 13:58:25 HOST kernel: [44033.150723] eth0: link up (100Mbps/Full duplex)
<6>Jan  2 12:01:00 HOST kernel: [194033.150723] loop7: detected capacity change from 0 to 113888

$ cat /tmp/logs/syslog.1
<29>Jan  1 13:58:25 HOST netifd: Network device 'eth0' link is up
<86>Jan  3 15:00:36 HOST dropbear[23732]: Exit (root): Disconnect received
```

Reprinting file `kernel.log` using `s4` looks like:

```
$ s4 --color=never -n -u -d '%s000000' /tmp/logs/kernel.log | tail -n1
kernel.log:1672689660000000:<6>Jan  2 12:01:00 HOST kernel: [194033.150723] loop7: detected capacity change from 0 to 113888
```

Notice the prepended fields are separated by `:` (the default).

Process each syslog-style log file under `/tmp/logs` into a corresponding journal file under path `/tmp/logsj`.
This sets `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER` to the file name, excluding file extensions. The created journal file is the name of the source file plus `.journal`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir /tmp/logsj

while read line; do
  echo "line is '${line}'"
  name=$(echo -n "${line}" | cut -f1 -d:)
  ts=$(echo -n "${line}" | cut -f2 -d:)
  mesg=$(echo -n "${line}" | cut -f3- -d:)
  jmesg="\
__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=${ts}
_TRANSPORT=syslog
MESSAGE_ID=$(uuidgen)
MESSAGE=${mesg}
SYSLOG_TIMESTAMP=${ts}
SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=${name%%.*}
_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=${ts}
"
  echo "${jmesg}" | /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote "--output=/tmp/logsj/${name}.journal" -
done <<< $(s4 --color=never -n -u -d '%s000000' /tmp/logs/)
```

Review the new journal files:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/logsj/
-rw-r----- 1 root root 8388608 Feb  3 14:36 kernel.log.journal
-rw-r----- 1 root root 8388608 Feb  3 14:36 syslog.1.journal

$ PAGER= journalctl --utc --output=short-full --directory=/tmp/logsj/
Sun 2023-01-01 21:58:25 UTC kernel: <6>Jan  1 13:58:25 HOST kernel: [44033.150723] eth0: link up (100Mbps/Full duplex)
Sun 2023-01-01 21:58:25 UTC syslog: <29>Jan  1 13:58:25 HOST netifd: Network device 'eth0' link is up
Mon 2023-01-02 20:01:00 UTC kernel: <6>Jan  2 12:01:00 HOST kernel: [194033.150723] loop7: detected capacity change from 0 to 113888
Tue 2023-01-03 23:00:36 UTC syslog: <86>Jan  3 15:00:36 HOST dropbear[23732]: Exit (root): Disconnect received
```

Run `journalctl` on a datetime slice

```
$ PAGER= journalctl --utc --output=short-full --until "2023-01-01 23:00:00 UTC" --directory=/tmp
/logsj/
Sun 2023-01-01 21:58:25 UTC kernel: <6>Jan  1 13:58:25 HOST kernel: [44033.150723] eth0: link up (100Mbps/Full duplex)
Sun 2023-01-01 21:58:25 UTC syslog: <29>Jan  1 13:58:25 HOST netifd: Network device 'eth0' link is up

$ PAGER= journalctl --utc --output=short-full --since "2023-01-01 23:00:00 UTC" --directory=/tmp
/logsj/
Mon 2023-01-02 20:01:00 UTC kernel: <6>Jan  2 12:01:00 HOST kernel: [194033.150723] loop7: detected capacity change from 0 to 113888
Tue 2023-01-03 23:00:36 UTC syslog: <86>Jan  3 15:00:36 HOST dropbear[23732]: Exit (root): Disconnect received
```

Comment: What happens when a journal is imported?  If journalctl trusts the imported "trusted journal fields", then a fake import file would work.

Comment: @PFudd great point! (doh!) Reviewing the docs a bit closer, there is a tool `systemd-journal-remote` for this import process.  I'll look into this further and reply.